# FatalError in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I generate one simple insert,update and delete application. when I run my application, I get error. my application files are below....

**Route.php**

```
Route::post('insertdata','ContactusController@store');
```

**ContactusController.php**

```
use App\ContactusModel;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/* namespaces */
use App\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class ContactusController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact.contact');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        ContactusModel::insertall($input);
        return view('contact.contact');
    }    
}
```

**ContactusModel.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ContactusModel extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'contactus_models';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['fullname','mobileno', 'email', 'message'];


    public static insertall($data)
    {
        return DB::table('users')->insert($data);
    }

}
```

I run this code. Error will be display like this....

```
FatalErrorException in ContactusModel.php line 24:
syntax error, unexpected 'insertall' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: `public static function insertall(...)` <-- you need the `function`

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static insertall($data)
    {
        return DB::table('users')->insert($data);
    }
```

You haven't added the word function

`public static function`

late night programming :P ?

Comment: Just realised - as watcher said also :D